# can't find .u variables when setting up ticker plant

Tags: kdb

I tried to follow what is on github for tick.q and u.q and sym.q.(https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/tree/master/), but unfortunately I get complaints on the variables below: .u.w, .u.i, .u.L, .u.d .u.tick, etc

where/how can I include these .u variable?

Comment: Could you please provide details of the error? How are you launching the tick system? What process are these errors incurring in?

Comment: Have you defined the functions in the appropriate `.u` namespace? Sounds like you haven't properly namespaced the functions